# Print array of elements into table or unordered list. jQuery or HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have an array of elements, I print them out using the following:

```
    function extractResult(result){     
        jQuery.each(result, function(index, value) {
            console.log(index, value); 
        });
    };
```

It prints out to the console like this:

> Mr.
>  Jim
>  00000001VKnAAL
>  Smith
>  sales
>   Prof.
>  3d000001VKkAAL

I want to print it out into a table or unordered list. Could anyone suggest how I could go about doing this?

I'm happy to use a dynamically generated jQuery table or unordered list if that would be best.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you give an example of how you'd like the final html to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but if all you're trying to do is just get the values from the array into the DOM, you can start with something like this and change it to whatever you'd like :

```
var list = $('<ul />'); // create UL
extractResult(array);   // run function and fill the UL with LI's
$('body').append(list); // append the completed UL to the body

function extractResult(result){     
    jQuery.each(result, function(index, value) {
        // create a LI for each iteration and append to the UL
        $('<li />', {text: index + ', ' + value}).appendTo(list);
    });
}
```

Comment: Cheers, this is perfect for now. And is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

As you want a suggestion and not the code. Use the same jQuery.each loop that you're using now but instead of outputting the stuff to the console, add it into an existing table structure using jQuerys .html method.